# How to map Shift-Tab in vim? (Cygwin, Windows cmd.exe)

Tags: windows, vim, tabs, cygwin, key

I see a few entries here about [making Shift-Tab work in vim](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Make_Shift-Tab_work), but none of them addresses the failure when it's in Cygwin, running at a Windows command prompt. In that environment, Shift-Tab works for me exactly like an unshifted tab, and my attempts at remapping have failed:

- `:imap <S-Tab> ^D`  [ this is a real Ctrl-D, entered with Ctrl-V before it ]
- `:imap` [ typed Ctrl-V, Shift-Tab here; got a Tab character inserted ]

So it seems that the Shift modifier is being ignored. Any thoughts about how to proceed? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That won't work in the Cygwin console because it sends the same keycode for both <kbd>Tab</kbd> and <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>: `^I`.

You might want to install Cygwin's [mintty](http://mintty.googlecode.com) terminal emulator, which sends the standard keycode for <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>: `\e[Z`.

Comment: Hah! I changed Cygwin's .profile to ...

`        nohup mintty &
        exit`

... then moved the previous startup commands to .bashrc. It works fine, and with only one window. Nice.

So the answer to the original question looks like "You can't do that, because Cygwin's native terminal window doesn't allow vi[m] to distinguish between a Tab and a Shift-Tab." Fair enough. Thanks.

Comment: But, but, installing the mintty package via Cygwin's setup.exe creates a mintty shortcut in the Cygwin folder of the start menu. No need to hack about with .profile.

Comment: mintty rocks!. if you work with gnu screen there is a tip in mintty website for defining <c-tab> and  <c-s-tab> to change screens :)

Comment: When I run mintty.exe directly, it doesn't know where the ls command, etc., are - Cygwin's executables aren't being added to $PATH. I suppose I could figure out how to get around that, but inasmuch as I have a working solution now, I'll make it a background task. Thanks for the heads-up.


Sorry for the lame message formatting, by the way. Mini-Markdown isn't treating me well - no blank lines; backticks didn't format as code; can't preview (not strictly MM, but still); Enter key caused not a newline but a "here, publish this" command (same); other problems.

Comment: If you start mintty without arguments, it will invoke your default shell as a non-login shell, which in the case of bash means that it sources `~/.bashrc` instead of `~/.profile` and `/etc/profile`, and the latter is where the `PATH` and various other things are set. It's the same with other terminals such as rxvt or xterm. To have the shell invoked as a login shell, start mintty with a single dash as its argument, like so: `mintty -`. This is what the shortcut in the Cygwin folder of the start menu does.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of messing with the Cygwin version, I suggest you remove it and install the [native version](http://www.vim.org/download.php#pc) instead. With that, you can map Shift-Tab without issues, even when starting Vim from a bash shell.

Comment: Thanks, but when I go into Cygwin - often! - I like to stay there as long as I can. For me, window swapping is a time sink.

Comment: @Singlestone: Are you using a special program to view your Cygwin shell, rather than running it in a normal Windows console window? The native version of Vim isn't just a GUI version; you also get a version running natively in the console, and Shift-Tab works perfectly fine in that.

Comment: Typically I invoke Cygwin with a link to Cygwin.bat in the install directory.

Comment: @Singlestone: IIRC, that's still the usual Windows console window that's being used. If so, there really isn't anything preventing you from using native Vim. (I stopped using Cygwin ages ago, so something might have changed so they start a different terminal by default, like rxvt. I use [GnuWin32](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/) to provide the typical GNU tools, and I have MSYS for when I really need bash - which is virtually never, except for running configure scripts.)

Answer (score 0):

I don't have windows right here now, but look whether your vimrc contains

```
behave mswin
source ...\mswin.vim
```

In that case,

```
:e +g/mswin/norm!\ 0i" $MYVIMRC
```

should automatically comment these out. Relaunch vim, and inspect whether there are existing mappings:

```
:verbose map <S-Tab>
```

will show you any existing mappings, and *where it was last defined*, so you can find the script/plugin that is causing this (`:he :verbose-cmd`)

HTH

---

**Update** *to the comment*:

Well - blimey, turns out [that Shift-Tab is magically impossible with Win32 Consoles](http://www.google.com/search?q=cmd+shift-tab+-mac+%2Bwindows). Never noticed.

Perhaps it is because I

- use **[mintty](http://code.google.com/p/mintty/)** these days, to provide a much better experience (Unix like copy pasting, real alternative terminals, more performance, and re-attaching screen sessions, e.g.)
- might have tweaked the [CompletionChar setting](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc784699%28WS.10%29.aspx) although this seems like a loose fodder even to me

Could you try with mintty? I'd think I'd have noticed such a hairy incompatibility over the years. But, you never know :)

Comment: Thanks. No joy, though. No `behave` or `source` statements in .vimrc or anywhere in `/usr/bin/vim`, and `:verbose map <S-Tab>` returns `No mapping found`.

Comment: @Singlestone: oo. Updated answer with thoughts. _Could you try with mintty?_